# How to check if a Discord.js snowflake is included in an array of other IDs

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, discord.js

I am currently working on a Discord.js bot and I'm trying to write a system where only given IDs in a JSON can execute the command. I do not know how to query this in an `if` statement.

```
if (message.author.id === config.admin) {
  if (cmd === 'mode') {
    let mode = args[0];
    if (mode === 'maintenance') {
      bot.user.setActivity(config.maintenanceGame);
      config.mode = 'maintenance';
      const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor("Gorded Media Ltd. - Maintenance", 'http://imageurl/logo.png')
        .setColor(color.red)
        .setDescription("The mode was set to `Maintenance`. All users can't use the commands in this mode.");
      message.channel.send(embed);
    }
    if (mode === 'online') {
      bot.user.setActivity(config.defaultGame);
      config.mode = 'online';
      const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor("Gorded Media Ltd. - Maintenance", 'http://imageurl/logo.png')
        .setColor(color.lime)
        .setDescription("The mode was set to `Online`. All users can use the commands in this mode.");
      message.channel.send(embed);
    }
    console.log(`[` + date + `] ` + config.consoleprefix + ` User ${message.author.tag} set the mode to ${config.mode}`);
  }
} else {
  message.channel.send(no_perms)
}
```

This is the structure of the JSON file parsed in `config`:

```
"admin": [
  "Discord Client ID",
  "Discord Client ID",
  "Discord Client ID"
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't check if the `message.author.id` is equal to `config.admin`, since that is an Array.
However, you can check if that Array contains the ID, using [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
if (config.admin.includes(message.author.id)) {...}
```